# How can I append new columns into csv in python?

Tags: python, csv

[INPUT]

```
listBox = ['status: 123', 'company: test']
```

[DESIRED OUTPUT]

```
'zzzz' - column A already exists
'status: 123' - should be written in column B in a single cell.  
'company: test' - should be written in column C in a single cell.
```

I've tried:

## Edit 1

```
def writeToCSV():
    checkpointList = ['CompanyID: test', 'StatusCode: 123']
    data = [str(checkpointList).split(",")]
    path = "output.csv"
    with open(path, "wb") as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for line in data:
            writer.writerow(line)
writeToCSV()
```

## But this will overwrite the existing columns

Comment: Will your input list contain only one record (as in the question) or will you have multiple records? How will the list be structured? Consider giving an example of a more extensive input list.

Comment: I have edited the python code. I do not want to overwrite existing columns from csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Try below- `writerow` expects single`list`.

```
import csv
def writeToCSV():
    checkpointList = ['CompanyID: test', 'StatusCode: 123']
    path = r"C:\out.txt"
    with open(path, "wb") as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow(checkpointList)
writeToCSV()
```

It writes-

```
CompanyID: test,StatusCode: 123
```

Comment: yes. thanks. But I want to append to existing data, not to overwrite existing data. I will keep investigatiing ...

Comment: I have tried the param 'ab'. It will not write existing data but it will add new row. I just want to add new columns. 'zzzz' - column A already exists
'status: 123' - should be written in column B in a single cell.  
'company: test' - should be written in column C in a single cell.

Comment: Do  you have  the complete and comprehensive list of column headers? Based on which cell values to be placed?

Comment: yes. the 'checkpointList ' list was just an example with > 1 member. The list should be appended (as new columns) to existing columns in the file.

Comment: I think the you should use `dictwriter`!

Comment: Managed to append column. Now I cannot write the list in different cells: import csv
f = open(r'C:\expected.csv')
data = [item for item in csv.reader(f)]
f.close()
checkpointList = ['CompanyID: test', 'StatusCode: 123']
print len(checkpointList)
checkpointList = [str(checkpointList).split(",")]
newData = []
for index, item in enumerate(data):        
        try:
            item.append(checkpointList)
        except:
            pass
        newData.append(item)
print "List that will be written :", newData
f = open('test2.csv', 'w')
csv.writer(f, delimiter=',').writerows(newData)
f.close()

Comment: would you share some dummy(?) data (but a complete skeleton of the real) with description what you want- i am in a loss..Sorry